# How can I check the validity of an input in angular, outside of a form and not checking for ng-invalid?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

How can I check if a field is valid without using a form as a parent?

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input
    #min
    matInput
    [ngModel]="min | transformMin"
    type="text"
    [pattern]="some-patern"
    (ngModelChange)="onChangeTransformMin($event)"
    (focusout)="updateMinMax()"
  />
</mat-form-field>
```

TS

Currently, I do it with

```
this.min.nativeElement.classList.contains('ng-invalid')
```

but I would like to do it some other way if possible?

Comment: You are using template-based forums for your example. Something that really helps with validation is "Reactive" based forms. You can find more here:https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms - From here, you can tell the FormControls (Each input) what validation checks it has to pass. Then you can get whether the control, or group of controls, is valid

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the field `min="ngModel"`

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input
    #min="ngModel"
    matInput
    [ngModel]="min | transformMin"
    type="text"
    [pattern]="some-patern"
    (ngModelChange)="onChangeTransformMin($event)"
    (focusout)="updateMinMax()"
  />
</mat-form-field>

<div *ngIf="min.errors.pattern">
    Invalid
</div>
```

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: I am using a one-way binding see [ngModel]="min | transformMin" I need to transform the value into MM:SS before I show it and back again to seconds on change see, onChangeTransformMin. Also I want to check in the ts file, not in the HTML

Answer (score 1):

The trick was to use

```
#min="ngModel"
```

and

```
@ViewChild('min') min: NgModel;
```

Then you can do a check for this.min.invalid in the ts file

```
if (this.min.invalid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min.errors` to find errors. If you have your field as required then you will get `min.errors.required true`, if your value doesnt match with pattern then `min.errors.pattern` will be available.

```
    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        #min="ngModel"
        matInput
        required
        [(ngModel)]="minObj"
        pattern="\d{1,5}"
        type="text"
        (ngModelChange)="onChangeTransformMin($event)"
        (focusout)="updateMinMax()"
      />
    </mat-form-field>
    <div *ngIf="min.errors && min.errors.required">Field is required!</div>
    <div *ngIf="min.errors && min.errors.pattern">Only allow Numbers!</div>
    <br /><br />
    <div *ngIf="min.errors">{{min.errors | json}}</div>
```

You can see it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-error-validation)